# Compilation performance problems while chaining template classes

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, g++

I wrote a set of template utilities that allows to create compile-time list of types and manipulate it in a style of functional programming.

The code had worked but I wasn't really happy with its interface (explained below) so I've tried to refactor it and while the new version is still working, it compiles too slow to be usable.

### The old, working code

I'll try to mock how it looks without copying hundreds of lines of code that make up the real version.

```
#include <stddef.h>

namespace typeList
{
    
    template<class ...TYPES>
    class List
    {
    public:
        TypeList() = delete;
        static constexpr size_t size = sizeof...(TYPES);
    };
    
    template<class LIST, size_t INDEX>
    using get = /*Some elaborate implementation*/;
    
    template<class LIST, size_t INDEX, class TYPE>
    using insert = /*Some elaborate implementation*/;
    
    template<class LIST, template<class> class MAPPER>
    using map = /*Some elaborate implementation*/;
    
    // There goes much more such "functions" but you should get the gist by now.
    
}
```

Using this looks more or less like this:

```
using initialList = typeList::List<bool, char>;
using tmp0 = typeList::insert<initialList, 1, void>; // List<bool, void, char>
using tmp1 = typeList::map<tmp0, SomeClass>; // List<SomeClass<bool>, SomeClass<char>, SomeClass<char>>
...
using finalResult = typeList::get<tmp26, 0>;
```

The program based on this version compiles in a reasonable time of 20-30s. Precompiled headers file with all the generated types takes about a 100MB.

### The new code

I wasn't happy with having to create a ton of immediate, single-use types because it litters the code and it is just annoying boilerplate. I've tried to rewrite my templates so they allow to chain them.

```
#include <stddef.h>

namespace typeList
{
    
    template<class ...TYPES>
    class List
    {
    public:
        TypeList() = delete;
        static constexpr size_t size = sizeof...(TYPES);
        
        template<size_t INDEX>
        using get = /*Some elaborate implementation*/;
        
        template<size_t INDEX, class TYPE>
        using insert = /*Some elaborate implementation*/;
        
        template<template<class> class MAPPER>
        using map = /*Some elaborate implementation*/;
        
        // There goes much more such "functions" but you should get the gist by now.
    };
    
}
```

Using the new version would look like this:

```
using initialList = typeList::List<bool, char>;
using finalResult = initialList
    ::insert<1, void> // List<bool, void, char>
    ::map<SomeClass> // List<SomeClass<bool>, SomeClass<char>, SomeClass<char>>
    ...
    ::get<0>;
```

My attempt of refactoring was half-successful. It does compile and it gives exactly the same result as the old version. However, it now takes about 3-10 minutes (more often 10) and the precompiled headers file has 2GB. (so basically both values raised 20 times)
Additionally, the compiler takes up to 8GB of RAM while working.

### The question

The question has two parts:

1. Why there is such a big discrepancy in performance of the compiler in these two cases?
2. Is it possible to fix the performance of the second version without loosing the nice way to interact with the templates?

I don't know why there is such a difference for the compiler. The syntax of the code has changed a little but the meaning of it is basically the same. It looks though like the compiler has to perform 20x more calculation on 20x more data!

My initial guess was that GCC tries to eagerly instantiate all types from `using` clauses in the `List` class but most of them are `template`s anyway so I don't see how compiler would be able to try that. Actually, in the full version of the code I had an `using` that was not a template and it had the compiler stuck in a loop of instantiating further and further results of it. Adding a dummy template parameter solved the problem which would suggest that `template` `using`s are instantiated on demand.

---

One more thing. I'm compiling the program for AVR and while I have the latest version of GCC I don't have access to the C++ standard library. Solution that involves anything aside from the C standard library would be appreciated but I still would prefer to something based on pure C++.

Comment: I kinda doubt this problem has a solution but I wasted too much time on it to not try to ask here :-/

Comment: I don't see anything here that would cause this behavior alone. It probably is related to the "elaborate implementations" you have omitted.

Comment: @cdhowie Maybe, but they have hardly change during the refactoring (beside of course the places where they were using other "functions" and had to be converted to the new interface). I don't really know how to include one in the question since the simple ones are likely not the cause and the more complex ones are long and base on the simple ones.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that something that was _conditionally_ instantiated before is now _unconditionally_ instantiated.  Are any of the `using` directives in the class _not_ a template? A non-template `using` that refers to a template on the RHS will unconditionally instantiate that template. Note also that a template `using` may be implemented with an underlying class type (possibly template) on some compilers.

Comment: @cdhowie I had a similar idea and yes, there was a few `using` directives that weren't templates, most notably one that extracts last type from the list by repeatably creating list shorter by the first element. However, there are two buts. The first is that this `using` was already a member of the `List` in the first version in an unchanged form, due to a little messy implementation. The second is that I already tried to find all non-template `using`s and add some dummy template parameters to them and that didn't seem to make any significant difference.

Comment: The only explanation I have then is all of the template-using declarations are responsible, assuming that there haven't been any changes to the RHS. For each instantiation of `List`, the compiler has to keep track of all of the template-using declarations regardless of whether or not they are used. In the original code, it looks like you have one template-using per meta-function. In the reworked code, you have one template-using per meta-function _per `List` instantiation._ Maybe that's the issue.

Comment: @cdhowie There was a few changes on RHS but as I wrote all (or almost all) of them was because the `using`s use each other. Maybe you right that the templates don't need to be instantiated to take that much memory / time and it is enough that they are present in every instantiation of `List`. I'm going to try to do the conversion from scratch and pay much more attention to when the problem starts to appear. This may take a few days. There will be a lot of digging through 20 pages of errors just to find a typo.

Comment: @cdhowie It has been some time. I took a break but now I've managed to finish may refactoring. I've wrote an answer with what I've learned.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: Everything below is my general observation and I'm at no point more than 90% percent sure they are correct.*

I've managed to finish the refactoring, keeping much more reasonable compilation performance. Now it is about 2 times the original time and memory usage (which is 10x less than the last attempt).

I don't have a comprehensive solution to the problem and I doubt any exists but there is a general guide on how to keep that kind of code in check.

---

## The cause of the problem

As far as I know, the sole reason for that slow compilation is an extraordinary eagerness of GCC to instantiate any and all templates as soon as it is possible, regardless of whether they are used or not.
It is not apparent in shorter programs and it seems to manifest only if the code is complex enough.

This behavior is pathological enough that in more complicated cases it may cause an infinite recursion.
For example the following code compiles fine but in more complicated program a similar pattern causes a `template instantiation depth exceeds maximum` error.

```
template<class T>
struct Bar;

template<class T>
struct Foo
{
    using goDeeper = Bar<Foo<T>>;
};

template<class T>
struct Bar
{
    using goDeeper = Foo<Bar<T>>;
};
```

I tried to prevent these eager instantiations by turning everything into templates with dummy parameters to make GCC thing that it does not have enough information to touch it. It sometimes works but other times GCC seems to be smart enough to detect that template parameter is unused.

It's quite hard to find exact code patterns that cause particular problems because firstly it starts to happen only if program is complex enough and secondly some of these behaviors seem to be quite random.
For this reason I can only give some general advice on how to write this kind of code.

---

## Methods to keep the compilation fast

### Use precompiled headers

This is a no brainer when it comes to problems with compilation speed but also it will be helpful for the next advice.

### Benchmark each change

The behavior of GCC during compilation of templates is very hard to predict. Sometimes one change can have barely any impact and another very similar change may absolutely wreck the performance. For this reason you should benchmark the compilation every time you are able to and be ready to revert to the previous version. (Keep a backup/checkpoint.)

Be careful when measuring time of the compilation. It may be quite unstable, differing a several dozen percent change while building the same source. In my case it was about 2x *faster* when I had a video playing in the background. (I was not able to reproduce this effect to that extend by using other forms of causing processor/memory load.)

It is a good idea to take the size of precompiled headers file as an additional indicator. It is very stable and it corelates with the time relatively closely.

### Split your template class

Instead of creating one big class with everything you need, try to split it into 2 or more in a following way. (I would suggests 3 levels.)

```
template<class ...TYPES>
class VeryBasicList
{
public:
    // Only the things that have negligible impact on performance here, e.g. pushBack.
    // Nothing that may use any form of recursion.
};

template<class ...TYPES>
class BasicList : public VeryBasicList<TYPES...>
{
public:
    // Things that may have some impact but they are commonly used to implement
    // more complex operations, e.g. popBack, get<N>.
};

template<class ...TYPES>
class List : public BasicList<TYPES...>
{
public:
    // Everything else you want to have.
};
```

After that, use that most basic class you are able, especially when implementing the most basic and commonly used operations, especially when they use recursion.

This method may decrease the compilation time a few times.

### Highly optimize basic operations

The operations that are used most often and that require the most levels of recursion have the biggest impact.

You may be tempted to compose some operations from more basic ones like using `reduce` to make `map` but this is a bad idea. The best is to write every basic thing independently.

The best approach to optimizing is simplicity. E.g. is the situation when you need to slice a list in half, it may seem to be a good idea to do in a single pass but when I tried that I've got a worse result than when I first cut the first half from the whole list and then the second part, again from the whole list. Perhaps it is like that because these simpler operations are used also in other places so they might overlap with something that was already instantiated.

### Avoid things that can cause infinite recursion

Try to not write anything that is possible to be expanded indefinitely without any additional instructions. Always put some kind of an end condition.

E.g.

```
template<class ...TYPES>
class List
{
public:
    using recursion = List<List<TYPES...>>;
};
```

Here compiler may go with instantiating `List<List<List<List<List<List<...` even not asked.

Instead write:

```
template<class ...TYPES>
class List;

template<class ORIGINAL_LIST, unsigned DEPTH>
class RecursionHelper
{
public:
    using result = typename RecursionHelper<List<ORIGINAL_LIST>, DEPTH-1>::result;
};
template<class ORIGINAL_LIST>
class RecursionHelper<ORIGINAL_LIST, 0>
{
public:
    using result = ORIGINAL_LIST;
};

template<class ...TYPES>
class List
{
public:
    template<unsigned DEPTH>
    using recursion = List<List<TYPES...>>;
};
```

Yes, that's a lot more writing but at least it won't explode at some random point, creating a hard to debug error.

### Try to keep the class small

If you have operation `RemoveIfConditionIsFalse`, you probably don't need `RemoveIfConditionIsTrue`. This is not that important since increasing number of class elements seems to have only linear impact on required memory and maybe even less on compilation speed but it's still a noticeable difference.